# FsCheck NUnit . Tests with condition

Tags: f#, nunit, fscheck

I'm trying to make test for this function

```
let extract_one_rule (rule:Rule.t<'a,'b>) = 
    let rec expand = function
    |PAlt     (a,b) -> expand a  @ expand b
    |PSeq     (a,b) -> let wrap = List.map (fun x -> (x.rule, fun r -> {x with rule = r})) a
                                  |> List.unzip
                       in
                       let rec gen = function
                           | hd::tl -> [for x in hd -> x :: ( gen tl |> List.concat)]
                           | []     -> []
                       in 
                       fst wrap |> List.map expand |> gen 
                       |> List.map (fun x -> PSeq ((List.map2 ( |> ) x (snd wrap)),b))
    |PRef   _ 
    |PLiteral _
    |PToken   _ as t   -> [t]
    | _             -> (System.Console.WriteLine("incorrect tree for alternative expanding!")
                        ; failwith "incorrect tree for alternative expanding!")
    in 
    expand rule.body |> List.map (fun x -> {rule with body = x})
```

using FsCheck
so i have this

```
let ExpandAlterTest(t : Rule.t<Source.t,Source.t> ) = convertToMeta t |> List.forall (fun x -> ruleIsAfterEBNF x)
```

but i'l see exception "incorrect tree for alternative expanding!"
but when i use smth like that

```
let ExpandAlterTest(t : Rule.t<Source.t,Source.t> ) = (correctForAlExp t.body) ==> lazy ( convertToMeta t |> List.forall (fun x -> ruleIsAfterEBNF x))
```

NUnit doesn't stop working
Why it can be?

Answer (score 3):

It could be that the precondition you added is very restrictive, so that it takes a long time before a good value (one that actually passes the precondition) is found. FsCheck is hardened against this - by default, it tries to find 100 values but when it has rejected 1000 it gives up and you should see a "Arguments exhausted after x tests" output. But this might take a long time, if generating and checking the value takes a long time.

Could also be that you actually have a bug somewhere, like an infinite loop.

Try changing the FsCheck config to run less tests, doing a verbose run (verboseCheck), and breaking in the debugger when it seems to hang.